# Angular Formly Individual fields

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Is there a way to display individual fields of the array rather than displaying all the fields?

Something like this,

```
$scope.fields = [{
   key:'firstName',
   type: 'input'
},{
   key:'lastName',
   type: 'input'   
}]

<formly-form model="model" field="fields[0]" form="userForm"></formly-form>

<formly-form model="model" field="fields[1]" form="userForm"></formly-form>
```

The reason I ask is because I need to make complicated html structures that need to go around each field.

Currently this is the only way I can do it. Which is very tedious and confusing when I pass the project to other developers.

```
$scope.field_1 = [{
   key:'firstName',
   type: 'input'
}]

$scope.field_2 = [{
   key:'lastName',
   type: 'input'   
}]

<formly-form model="model" fields="field_1" form="userForm"></formly-form>

<formly-form model="model" fields="field_2" form="userForm"></formly-form>
```

Comment: You should just be able to use dot notation, if I'm not mistaken; fields[0].key   or fields[1].type, for instance.

Comment: `Formly` fields takes an array as the input. so you can structure your json as an array of array to get the results you are looking for. Something like `$scope.fields = [[{   key:'firstName',   type: 'input'}],[{   key:'lastName',   type: 'input'   }]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Formly` fields takes an array as the input. so you can structure your json as an array of array to get the results you are looking for.

Something like

```
$scope.fields = [[{
   key:'firstName',
   type: 'input'
}],[{
   key:'lastName',
   type: 'input'   
}]]
```

Here is a JSbin with an example http://jsbin.com/waqilejati/edit?html,js,output